# How does TypeScript infer generic type from multiple arguments of function call?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Look at the following function:

```
function is<T>(a: T, ...b: [T, ...T[]]): boolean {
  return b.every(_ => _ === a)
}

is(10, 'foo')
is([1], 'foo')
```

When we call it as `is(10, 'foo')` we get `error TS2345: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'`.

But when we call it as `is([1], 'foo')` we get `error TS2345: Argument of type 'number[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'`.

Why in the first case the `T` is bound to 'number', but in the second case the `T` is bound to 'string', not to 'number[]', and therefore TypeScript throws a squiggly at `[1]`, not `'foo'`?

Comment: Here's a [simpler reproduction case](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZjAvDAPAFQDQD4AUAPALhkxgDpyBPItAbQF0BKIgNxAEsATJLGAbxlCQQAGwCmpYSADm+DDAoMA3DAC+ygFBwcNAIx05AcgAWbA0piacx03J1L1QA). This only seems to happen with rest params though, I can't reproduce it if I just have a plain `T[]` as the second param.

Comment: Hi @JaredSmith 
If we simplify the function to just:
```
function is<T>(a: T, b: T): boolean {
  return b === a
}

and call it with the same arguments as before we get the same result:
`is(10, 'foo') // error TS2345: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'`
`is([1], 'foo') // error TS2345: Argument of type 'number[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'`

The question is why TypeScript throws a squiggly at [1], not 'foo' in the second call? Why TypeScript doesn't infer generic type from the first argument of function call, i.e. `[1]`?

Comment: Yes, the question is very clear, you can see the same issue in the link I gave. Having played around with it it *seems like* TS preferentially infers generics from parameters in this order primitives > built in object types like RegExp, Date, etc and  user defined class instances > Arrays > object literals. Within the same 'category' it's whichever is used first, but values from a 'higher' category always trump lower ones in inferring the generic regardless of order.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBA5jAvDAPAFQDQD4AUAPALhkxgE8i0BKIgNxAEsATJLGAbxgCgYeZRIQAGwCmAOkEg4+DGUoBuLgF85nTlLDCA7jAAiAQyjCZAcgAWwwROOU1OANoBGALoyN2-YZtSA9HoBGwN4m-sDWtnbGIcYuML4B3l44kcYyDokATMFhUo4xcYGJuTIRetGFzsVuugbCTolVHkaxIQm2bIquWtWetvlBMA01iRx6RA4wHQNdjcMwozDjk+02nMCCehAQMABiICDs3Lx6SAucirZVuyCd7kMXXVcyy20wfkRm9MYTNzt75TGXP73W6GH5Xf5POZjCY2IA

Comment: Unfortunately none of the work I did on this answers the question of *why* Typescript prioritizes generic type resolution the way it does, I'm hoping somebody more familiar with the compiler internals will see this and write an answer.

Comment: https://tsplay.dev/wRAgLW